# Create MS-Access Report without displaying the rows of records

Tags: ms-access

I am relatively new to using Access.  I would prefer to write a front end in C# but my place of work won't allow any custom software on their computers so I am forced to run things from access.

I have a db set up which has questions from exam papers.  I can query to retrieve a question which includes the names of the image files which I want to display on a report.  Here is the data generated.

```
image_page  image_filename  paper_name  question_number
0   2022-H556-03-01-0.png   H556-03 1
1   2022-H556-03-01-1.png   H556-03 1
```

I can create a report based on this query but it shows the rows of records (which I guess is normal behaviour for a db query).  However, I want to use the data in the rows to display the image files from their filenames (the images are stored in a folder of known location relative to the access database).

I don't want to 'see' the records per se, just an image per record.  I am not clear how to achieve this in Access.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Put this question to _Copilot_, and she will in seconds return the four steps needed plus the full explanation as well as useful links: _Using Microsoft Access and a report bound to a table holding the filenames of images, how can the report display those images, please?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assume a table (or query) with the following data:

| ID | ImageName | ImageFile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | b1.png |
| 2 | Two | b2.png |
| 3 | Three | b3.png |
| 4 | Four | b4.png |
| 5 | Five | b5.png |
| 6 | Six | b6.png |

So, in Access, select the above table (or query) and click on report.

Say this:

[image]

Let's now flip report into design mode, remove the format layout, and we then from the ribbon drop in the image control to the report.

So drag + drop from the ribbon a image control. When the wizards prompt for a file, hit cancel.

So, then this in design mode:

[image]

Now, it is a simple matter to type in a expression that produces a string path name + the data base column "image" name.

First, setup the image control to use a path name (linked image). Thus this setting will mean a external image from Access.

[image]

Now, on the data tab of the image control (still on properties sheet for the image control), then this expression:

[image]

Now, just flip the report into preview mode, and you are done, and zero lines of code written here so far:

So, in LESS time then it took to write this post, we now have this report:

[image]

So, you can "feed" the image control a valid expression, and that expression can include a path name, and a column from the current record for the given row of data.

As above shows, you can thus display multiple images in a report. No real coding is required. You could have even say used a SQL expression in the query, and feed that to the report.

There are several image controls, make sure you choose/use the newer one, as the older ones don't support path names, and don't support newer image formats like png etc.

Of course, if we don't want the column information, then just go on a delete party and remove such controls from the report.

So, un-check header, footer, and thus we have this:

[image]

So, above is quite much empty. When above is viewed, we have this:

[image]

And we could add a page break after each image. It really depends if you need/want multiple images per page, or what kind of layout you are looking for. But, as above shows, little stops you from removing the columns, headings etc., and the result is just a simple image control without column data being displayed.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such a detailed answer.  That is brilliant.